# creating a text link using p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, href, p5.js

I am currently trying to create a website entirely using p5.js. I would like to create a link, that will direct me to another page on the website.

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
function setup(){
link = text("this is a link", 120, 120);
}

function draw(){
  if (link.mousePressed){
    link(www.example.com); //does the processing link function move to p5?
}
```

Assuming something like this would not work, could I do something coordinate based?

```
function setup(){
link = text("this is a link", 120, 120);
}

function mousePressed(){
  if (mouseY == 120 && mouseX >= 110 && <= 130){ //range accounting for text length
    link(www.example.com);
}
```

If neither of the above were possible, could I make use of the p5 DOM.JS library?

```
text("<a href='http://www.google.com'>Enter Locke Design</a>", 120, 120);
```

Hopefully someone can shed some light or point me in the right direction! Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 2):

I used this and worked for me:

```
function mousePressed(){
  if (mouseY >= 100 && mouseY <= 120 && mouseX >= 110 && mouseX <= 130){ 
    //range accounting for text length
    window.open("http://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing doesn't make a ton of sense. The `text()` function simply draws some text to your screen. It doesn't have anything to do with HTML or creating a link.

The link function returns HTML that you can append to your document to create a link. It doesn't make sense to call it like you're calling it, and you're going to get an error since you aren't even quoting your string values. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_str_link) for an example of using the `link()` function.

If you want to use the `text()` function, then you're on the right track with the `if` statement that checks the mouse position. But notice that you're checking whether `mouseY` is **exactly** equal to `120`, which only gives you a single pixel to click on. Then the second part of your `if` statement is not valid syntax, as you can't just string conditions along with the `&&` operator. You need a complete inequality there.

Taking a step back, you're getting confused because you're mixing up two approaches: displaying something using P5.js (the `text()` function), and displaying something using HTML (the `link()` function). Mixing them doesn't make sense. You need to choose one approach and go with that.

Taking another step back, I'm not sure that creating a full website using P5.js is a great approach. Sure it's possible using the P5.dom library, but that's designed more for adding functionality to an existing webpage. If you know you want a link in the page every time it loads, then just put that in your HTML. That's what it's for.

Comment: Could createA() be used in this scenario?

Comment: @LukeGarrigan Maybe, but like I mentioned, the first step is to decide whether you want links in the web page, or clickable text in the sketch.

Answer (score 1):

Using window.open(... will work for P5js apps but it is not ideal from a UX standpoint because depending on browser settings and popup blockers the visitor may have installed, the visitor will most likely get a warning message about opening a pop-up before the link is opened

Using createA(href, html, [target]);, or in the case of creating any HTML element from P5js, it is generally really difficult to position the HTML element correctly relative to the P5js canvas, especially if you have a responsive website

One technique I have used to present clickable links to the user is to make the P5js app display an HTML div like a popup modal dialog, this will not be blocked by popup blockers from what I understand

Here is an example:

HTML

```
<div id="puzzle_canvas_id"></div>

<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none; position:fixed; top:20%; left:30%; width:20%; padding-bottom:50px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#999; border-radius:10px; background-color:#fff; z-index:9999">';
<p >Popup message...</p>
<a href="https://my-url.com">click here</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
function setup() {
var canvas = createCanvas(320, 240);
canvas.parent('puzzle_canvas_id');
}

function draw() {
}

function mouseClicked() {
var elem = document.getElementById('popup-modal'); 
elem.style.display = 'block'; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
createA(href, html, [target]);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.